# Check if a column of a pandas dataframe contains a substring for each row of a different column?

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, iteration

I have been stuck on what I considered originally to be a simple task for quite some while. Here I will use sample data as the actual problem data is much messier (and confidential). Essentially I have two columns both containing strings. I want to check for each row of column 'substring', if it is a substring of any of the rows of column 'string':

```
s1 = ['good', 'how', 'hello', 'start']
s2 = ['exit', 'hello you','where are you', 'goodbye']
test = pd.DataFrame({'substring':s1, 'string':s2})
>>> test

    string           substring
0   exit             good
1   hello you        how
2   where are you    hello
3   goodbye          start
```

Essentially I would like some indicator for each row if column A if it is a substring of anywhere in column B:

```
>>>test
    string           substring   C
0   exit             good        True
1   hello you        how         False
2   where are you    hello       True
3   goodbye          start       False
```

I have seemed to tried many things and I have just become lost.

I have tried iterating over the rows:

```
sub_test = pd.DataFrame(columns=test.columns)

    for index, row in test.iterrows():
        a = row['substring']
        delta = test[test['string'].str.contains(a)]
        if len(delta.index > 1):
            sub_test = pd.concat([sub_test, delta])
```

Which gets me some of the way and returns:

```
>>>sub_test

    string      substring
3   goodbye     start
1   hello you   how
```

I would think there is a way of doing this using lambda but I have not been successful:

`test['C'] = test.apply(lambda row: row['substring'] in policies['substring'], axis = 1)`

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Form one big pattern that we use to extract all substrings. Then we use an `isin` check to see if the `substring` matched anywhere.

```
p = '('+'|'.join(test.substring)+')'
test['C'] = test['substring'].isin(test['string'].str.extractall(p)[0].unique())

  substring          string      C
0      good            exit   True
1       how  hello good you  False
2     hello   where are you   True
3     start         goodbye  False
```

---

This works by `str.extractall` returning a DataFrame with matches.

```
test['string'].str.extractall(p)

             0
  match       
1 0      hello
3 0       good
```

The index is related to `test`'s index, not important here, with another level indicating the match number (since we use `.extractall`). The value is the substring that was matched. Since our capturing group contained specific words (not a general pattern), we can use an equality check (`isin`) to get the mask for the `'substring'` values.